# How to create a unique list of json elements using node js with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to create an application that the user added to the database a json file. This file has three properties: Name, Id and another value, I need that the id will be unique, and if the user tries to create another user with this id he will get an error message.

I tried to create a unique object, but of course it didn't worked (Using mongoose Scema):

```
    var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    list_users_ticket: {type: [{
        whoChecked_name: String,
        whoChecked_id: String,
        what_checked: String
    }], unique: true},
    name : { type: String, required: true } ,
    reg_id: { type: String, required: true, unique: true }

});


mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://------------');

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

// make this available to our users in our Node applications
module.exports = User;
```

And this is how I use it in dbRequests:

```
   exports.update = function(cur_reg_id, user_ticked) {

    User.find({reg_id: cur_reg_id},function(err, users){
       //removeusers(cur_reg_id);
        if (err) throw err;

        var len = users.length;
        console.log("Len" + len)

        if(len == 0 || len > 1){

                callback({'response':"You didn't register"});

        } else {



// Here I want to check if the value exist or not, and if yes, update the jsn filed like the code below :)


                users[0].list_users_ticket.push(user_ticked);
                console.log(users[0])

                users[0].save(function(err) {
                    if (err) throw err;

                    callback({'response':"User Saved   " + user_ticked});

                });

        }});



        //console.log('User successfully updated!');
}
```

This code does not work for me. I can to iterate through all the elements in this list, but this will consume a lot of power in the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexes do not work like that. The intention is that the elements are "unique" thoughout the "collection" and not the document, not certainly not the the array items within a document

For your very simple case of "unique" items with all values to each key of the array sub-document, then the answer is [**`$addToSet`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/update/addToSet/).

### But there are Bugs here

Whilst the `$addToSet` operator would be the correct thing to do here, Mongoose is presently not playing nicely, and specifically it is re-ordering the keys in the objects to be added, thus making an otherwise identical object no longer identical.

From the MongoDB perpective, if the keys are not in the same order as an object already in the array, then it is not the "same" and a new object would be added. Such re-ordering renders `$addToSet` as an operator useless in this case.

The only workaround here is to test for the presence of the object in an array in a way where the order of keys is not important, as is generally the case with query operators. So using an [**`$elemMatch`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) with a [**`$not`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/not/) condition should do the trick:

```
{
  "list_users_ticket": {
    "$not": {
        "$elemMatch": {
            "whoChecked_name": "bob",
            "whoChecked_id": "1",
            "what_checked": "something"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

As a complete demonstration:

```
var async = require('async'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/usertest');
mongoose.set("debug",true);

var ticketSchema = new Schema({
  whoChecked_name: String,
  whoChecked_id: String,
  what_checked: String
},{ "_id": false });

var userSchema = new Schema({
  list_users_ticket: [ticketSchema]
});

var User = mongoose.model( "User", userSchema );

var userData = {
  whoChecked_name: "bob",
  whoChecked_id: "1",
  what_checked: "something"
};

var query = {
  "list_users_ticket": {
    "$not": {
      "$elemMatch": userData
    }
  }
};

function logger(data) {
  return JSON.stringify( data, undefined, 2 );
}

async.waterfall(
  [
    function(callback) {
      User.remove({},function(err) {
        callback(err);
      })
    },
    function(callback) {
      var user= new User({ "list_users_ticket": userData });
      user.save(function(err,user) {
        callback(err,user);
      });
    },
    function(user,callback) {
      console.log("Previous State: %s", logger(user));
      query["_id"] = user._id;
      User.findOneAndUpdate(
        query,
        { "$push": { "list_users_ticket": userData } },
        { "new": true },
        function(err,doc) {
          if (err) callback(err);
          console.log("Modified: %s", logger(doc));
          callback();
        }
      );
    },
    function(callback) {
      User.findOne({},function(err,user) {
        if (err) callback(err);
        console.log("Current: %s", logger(user));
        callback();
      });
    }
  ],
  function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }
);
```

With output:

```
Mongoose: users.remove({}) {}
Mongoose: users.insert({ _id: ObjectId("55cffae0b5fd68c324e6934b"), list_users_ticket: [ { whoChecked_name: 'bob', whoChecked_id: '1', what_checked: 'something' } ], __v: 0 })
Previous State: {
  "__v": 0,
  "_id": "55cffae0b5fd68c324e6934b",
  "list_users_ticket": [
    {
      "whoChecked_name": "bob",
      "whoChecked_id": "1",
      "what_checked": "something"
    }
  ]
}
Mongoose: users.findAndModify({ _id: ObjectId("55cffae0b5fd68c324e6934b"), list_users_ticket: { '$not': { '$elemMatch': { whoChecked_name: 'bob', whoChecked_id: '1', what_checked: 'something' } } } }) [] { '$push': { list_users_ticket: { what_checked: 'something', whoChecked_id: '1', whoChecked_name: 'bob' } } } { new: true, upsert: false, remove: false }
Modified: null
Mongoose: users.findOne({}) { fields: undefined }
Current: {
  "_id": "55cffae0b5fd68c324e6934b",
  "__v": 0,
  "list_users_ticket": [
    {
      "whoChecked_name": "bob",
      "whoChecked_id": "1",
      "what_checked": "something"
    }
  ]
}
```

The check in here essentially makes sure that no matching element is found in the array for the data to be inserted and hence otherwise will not match the document at all. Whilst this is not exactly the same behaviour as an `$addToSet` operation, the result is the same in terms of whether the item is added to the array or not.

Depending on your needs, this may or may not require a little more work, but it is the workaround until something is done to preserve and not alter the the order of object keys when performing an `$addToSet` operation such as this.

---

### Original content

A little demonstration assuming `User` as the model to the associated schema, and that the "index" constraint is removed and purged from the database. The [async.waterfall](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall) helps with the flow here as well:

```
var async = require('async'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/usertest');
mongoose.set("debug",true);

var ticketSchema = new Schema({
  whoChecked_name: String,
  whoChecked_id: String,
  what_checked: String
},{ "_id": false });

var userSchema = new Schema({
  list_users_ticket: [ticketSchema]
});

var User = mongoose.model( "User", userSchema );

var userData = {
  whoChecked_name: "bob",
  whoChecked_id: "1",
  what_checked: "something"
};

function logger(data) {
  return JSON.stringify( data, undefined, 2 );
}

async.waterfall(
  [
    function(callback) {
      User.remove({},function(err) {
        callback(err);
      })
    },
    function(callback) {
      var user= new User({ "list_users_ticket": userData });
      user.save(function(err,user) {
        callback(err,user);
      });
    },
    function(user,callback) {
      console.log("Previous State: %s", logger(user));
      User.findByIdAndUpdate(user._id,
        { "$addToSet": { "list_users_ticket": userData } },
        { "new": true },
        function(err,doc) {
          if (err) callback(err);
          console.log("Modified: %s", logger(doc));
          callback();
        }
      );
    }
  ],
  function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }
);
```

And that will show that when you add the "exact same detail" to the member of the"set" then the result is that nothing additional is added.

So you **dot not** use indexes for this, but rather control logic as demonstrated.

---

**Big Edit**

---

Another **Huge** Mongoose bug. Here are the details on a current mongoose release from the listed code:

```
Mongoose: users.remove({}) {}
Mongoose: users.insert({ _id: ObjectId("55cf60bc5fd3f5a70937190b"), list_users_ticket: [ { whoChecked_name: 'bob', whoChecked_id: '1', what_checked: 'something' } ], __v: 0 })
Previous State: {
  "__v": 0,
  "_id": "55cf60bc5fd3f5a70937190b",
  "list_users_ticket": [
    {
      "whoChecked_name": "bob",
      "whoChecked_id": "1",
      "what_checked": "something"
    }
  ]
}
Mongoose: users.findAndModify({ _id: ObjectId("55cf60bc5fd3f5a70937190b") }) [] { '$addToSet': { list_users_ticket: { what_checked: 'something', whoChecked_id: '1', whoChecked_name: 'bob' } } } { new: true, upsert: false, remove: false }
Modified: {
  "_id": "55cf60bc5fd3f5a70937190b",
  "__v": 0,
  "list_users_ticket": [
    {
      "whoChecked_name": "bob",
      "whoChecked_id": "1",
      "what_checked": "something"
    },
    {
      "what_checked": "something",
      "whoChecked_id": "1",
      "whoChecked_name": "bob"
    }
  ]
}
```

See how the "key order" is different in the newly inserted "set" entry. Still even wondering how MongoDB itself accepts this.

Whereas the standard node driver listing:

```
var async = require("async"),
    mongodb = require("mongodb");
    MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

var userData = {
  who_checked_name: "bob",
  whoChecked_id: "1",
  what_checked: "something"
};

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/usertest',function(err,db) {

  function logger(data) {
    return JSON.stringify( data, undefined, 2 );
  }

  var collection = db.collection('users');

  async.waterfall(
    [
      function(callback) {
        collection.remove({},function(err) {
          console.log("did that");
          callback(err);
        });
      },
      function(callback) {
        collection.insert({ "list_users_ticket": [userData] },function(err,doc) {
          console.log("that too");
          callback(err,doc);
        });
      },
      function(user,callback) {
        console.log( logger(user) );
        collection.findOneAndUpdate(
          { "_id": user._id },
          { "$addToSet": { "list_users_ticket": userData } },
          { "returnOriginal": false },
          function(err,doc) {
            if (err) callback(err);
            console.log( logger(doc) );
            callback();
          }
        );
      }
    ],
    function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      db.close();
    }
  );
});
```

Does things correctly and and expected:

```
{
  "result": {
    "ok": 1,
    "n": 1
  },
  "ops": [
    {
      "list_users_ticket": [
        {
          "who_checked_name": "bob",
          "whoChecked_id": "1",
          "what_checked": "something"
        }
      ],
      "_id": "55cf62024cceb3ed181a7fbc"
    }
  ],
  "insertedCount": 1,
  "insertedIds": [
    "55cf62024cceb3ed181a7fbc"
  ]
}
{
  "lastErrorObject": {
    "updatedExisting": true,
    "n": 1
  },
  "value": {
    "_id": "55cf62024cceb3ed181a7fbc",
    "list_users_ticket": [
      {
        "who_checked_name": "bob",
        "whoChecked_id": "1",
        "what_checked": "something"
      }
    ]
  },
  "ok": 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! How can I use async.waterfall? what is that even meen?

Comment: @user3421416 I actually meant to include a link and now I have. This is basic "flow control" for async functions as a "helper". The listing here is otherwise "complete". Just make an app with the dependecies to see the results.

Comment: But I didn't understand it. I am not sure that you understand what I want: I want to just add a unique value to a list of json files. In more 5 min I will update my answer with the full schema, and how dow I use it, and maybe then it will be clear, Sorry abot my english. And sorry about my misunderstanding :)

Comment: @user3421416 You **cannot** use an "index" for this. An index is "collection wide", so no other document can have the same value, and not just restrictive to arrays "within" a document. `$addToSet` makes sure the array elements remain "unique" and "within" the document itself. You cannot add another with the same properties. The example here is "self contained". Run it and see the result.

Comment: "async is not defined" - what should I do? Thanks you very much And btw I updated my code. I am not sure if I use t correctly, I just copied and paste it into the "else" in the update method. And of course I canged the userData.

Comment: @user3421416 umm. set up your project ( and a clean one ) correctly. `npm init -y` and hopefully that does not prompt you if you have settings correct. Then in the folder for the project `npm install async --save && npm install mongoose --save` then just run the file you place in that folder for the project.  Many basic tutorials for this.

Comment: But all this things worked until now. I don;t know where async come from, it maked sense that this come up with an error. I will do what you asked, but I am pretty sure that it will stay the same. Do you saw my updated code and you think he is ok?

Comment: I copy and pasted the code, npm i async, but now it just don't do nothing. This is the link for my new update code: http://pastebin.com/zhaf2ymU

Comment: @user3421416 This is just and "example". I am demonstrating adding the **exact** same object to the array with two statements. You do not **need** to do this in your own code. It is just a demonstration of what `$addToSet` ( the whole point of the answer ) does.

Comment: Ok, so now it a lot clearer :) Thanks!
But the list still always updating itself when I use it. Do you have an idea why? where do I tell it not to add if it found the id is same?

Comment: @user3421416 If you are following the example I have created then what you claim is not possible. The only way you get additional entries in the array is if the entry you are adding differs in one of the properties. In the definition of a "set" this makes that item "unique". And therefore a completely different question to what you asked. Consider the answer in the context of the question you asked, and if that leads you to other questions, then post another question.

Comment: Ok, so as you asked, I came here again :) So how can I add a diffrent json object as i asked? your solution didn't worked for me .

Comment: @user3421416 So sorry. It appears you have inadvertantly stumbled upon a bug in the current mongoose release. See the details in the answer.

Comment: So what should I do? Thanks, again :)

Comment: @user3421416 I've added an explanation of how to work around this using other query conditions instead of `$addToSet`.